# Scanner пропускает строки

Tags: java, scanner

проблема заключается в том что при считывании данных с клавиатуры с помощью методов класса Scanner, он пропускает строки (Date и Notes). Насколько я понял передается символ '\n' или '\0' конца строки с предыдущего ввода.

```
public void add() {
    Magazine a = new journal();
    System.out.println("Add journal");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Titre of journal");
    String titre= sc.nextLine();
    a.setTitre(titre);

    System.out.println("Price journal");
    float prix=sc.nextFloat();
    a.setPrix(prix);

    //ВОТ ЭТУ
    System.out.println("Date of Magazine");
    date= sc.nextLine();
    a.setDate(date);

    System.out.println("Category of journal");
    int category = sc.nextInt(); 
    a.setCategory(category);

    //ВОТ ЭТУ
    System.out.println("Notes of journal");
    String notes = sc.nextLine(); 
    a.setNotes(notes);

    Bibliotheque.GetList().add(a);
}
```

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, не могли бы вы его принять?

Answer (score 5):

Всё дело в том, что команды `next()`, `nextFloat()` и т.д. - они читают только токет, то есть последовательность символов, которые не являются управляющими. Поэтому когда вы пишите `nextFloat()` и потом `nextLine()`, то `Scanner` сначала прочитает `Float`, а потом в следующем запросе будет идти до конца строки, которая наступит прямо вот сразу.

Вот так это будет работать:

```
public void add() {
    System.out.println("Add journal");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Titre of journal");
    String titre= sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Price journal");
    float prix=sc.nextFloat();
    sc.nextLine();

    //ВОТ ЭТУ
    System.out.println("Date of Magazine");
    String date= sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Category of journal");
    int category = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    //ВОТ ЭТУ
    System.out.println("Notes of journal");
    String notes = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println(titre);
    System.out.println(prix);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(category);
    System.out.println(notes);
}
```

Результат:

```
Add journal
Titre of journal
>> sdflkj sdkfsd sdf
Price journal
>> 123.1
Date of Magazine
>> 12.12.12
Category of journal
>> 2
Notes of journal
>> dsfs fsdf sdf jdskfjksdf 

sdflkj sdkfsd sdf
123.1
12.12.12
2
dsfs fsdf sdf jdskfjksdf
```

Чтобы понять как это лучше работать, я бы советовал вам глянуть исходник функции nextInt(). Он довольно простой, но покажет как это работает.